# Pycharm does not launch from other directory even after editing .bashrc, .profile and .environment

Tags: bash, bashrc, paths

I downloaded PyCharm, and from the directory where the executable `pycharm.sh` is, it works fine, however, whenever I do `sudo vim ~/.profile`, `sudo vim ~/.bashrc`, and add `export PATH="$HOME/pycharm-2023.2.1:$PATH"` as the last line, or `sudo vim /etc/environment` and append the installation directory as `...:home/my_username/pycharm-2023.2.1` to the path there, and source the corresponding files, it never works.

Same problem for Android-Studio and other programs that are not installed through sudo or snap.